# Agile practices to avoid deprecated code?

Tags: api, agile, deprecated

I am converting an open source Java library to C#, which has a number of methods and classes tagged as deprecated. This project is an opportunity to start with a clean slate, so I plan to remove them entirely. However, being new to working on larger projects, I am nervous that the situation will arise again. Since much of agile development revolves around making something work now and refactoring later if needed, it seems like deprecation of APIs must be a common problem. Are there preventative measures I can take to avoid/minimize API deprecation, even if I am not entirely sure of the future direction of a project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure there is much you can do. Requirements change, and if you absolutely have to make sure that clients of the API are not broken by newer API version, you'll have rely on simply deprecating code until you think that no-one is using the deprecated code.

Placing [Obsolete] attributes on code causes the compiler to create warnings if there are any references to the obsolete methods. This way clients of the API, if they are diligent about fixing their compiler warnings, can gradually move to the new methods without having everything break with the new version.

Its useful if you use the ObsoleteAttribute's override which takes a string:

```
[Obsolete("Foo is deprecated. Use Bar instead for munging widgets.")]
```

<frivolous>

Perhaps you could create a TimeBombAttribute:

```
[TimeBomb(new DateTime(2010,1,1), "Foo will blow up! Better use Bar, or else."]
```

In your code, reflect for methods with the timebomb attribute and throw KaboomException if they are called after the specified date. That'll make sure that after 1st January 2010 no-one is using the obsolete methods, and you can clean up your API nicely. :)

</frivolous>

Comment: +1: API change is the norm, not an exception.  If API's aren't changing, your code base is dead and no one care about adapting it to new purposes.

Answer (score 5):

As Matt says, the [`Obsolete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute is your friend... but whenever you apply it, provide details of how to change calling code. That way you've got a lot better chance of people actually changing. You might also want to consider specifying which version you anticipate removing the method in (probably the next major release).

Of course, you should be diligent in making sure *you* don't call the obsolete code - particularly in sample code.

Answer (score 2):

> Since much of agile development revolves around making something work now and refactoring later if needed

That's not agile. It's cowboy coding disguised under the label of agile.

The ideal is that whatever you complete, is **complete**, according to whatever Definition of Done you have. Usually the DoD states something along the lines of "feature impelmented, tested and related code refactored". Of course, if you are working on a throwaway prototype, you can have a more relaxed DoD.

API modifications are a difficult beast. If they are only project-internal APIs you are modifying, the best way to go is to refactor early. If you need to change the internal API, just go ahead and change all API clients at the same time. This way the refactoring debt does not grow very large and you don't have to use deprecation.

For published APIs you probably have some source and binary compatibility guarantees you have to maintain, at least until the next major release or so. Marking the old APIs deprecated works while maintaining compatibility. As with internal APIs, you should fix your internal code as soon as possible to not use the deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer is solid advice. I just wanted to mention that intially you probably want to use something along the lines of:

```
[Obsolete("Please use ... instead ", false)]
```

Once you have the code ported, change the false to true and the compiler will then treat all the calls to the method as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Watch Josh Bloch's "[How to Design a Good API and Why It Matters](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3733345136856180693)"

Most important w/r/t deprecation is knowing that "when in doubt, leave it out."  Watch the video for clarification, but it has to do with having to support what you provide forever.  If you are realistically expecting that API to be reused, you're effectively setting your decisions in stone.

I think API design is a much trickier thing to do in an Agile fashion because you're expecting it to be reused probably in many different ways.  You have to worry about breaking others that are dependent on you, and so while it can be done, it's tough to have the right design emerge without getting a quick turnaround from other teams.  Of course deprecation is going to help here, but I think **YAGNI** is a lot better design heuristic when it comes to APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think deprecation of code is an inevitable byproduct of Agile processes like continuous refactoring and incremental development.  So if you end up with deprecated code as you work on your project, that's not necessarily a bad thing--just a fact of life.  Of course, you will probably find that, rather than deprecating code, you end up keeping a lot of code but refactoring it into different methods, classes, and so on.

So, bottom line: I wouldn't worry about deprecating code during Agile development.  If it served its purpose for a while, you're doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb for API design is to focus on what it does, rather than how it does it. Once you know the end goal, figure out the absolute minimum input you need and use that. Avoid passing your own objects as parameters, pass only data.

Seperate configuration from execution. For exmaple, maybe you have an image encoder/decoder.

Instead of making a call like:

```
Encoder.Encode( bytes, width, height,  compression_type, compression_ratio, palette, etc etc);
```

Make it

```
Encoder.setCompressionType(compression_type);
Encoder.setCompressionType(compression_ratio);
etc,etc
Encoder.Encode(bytes, width, height);
```

That way adding or removing settings is much less likely to break existing implementations.

Answer (score 0):

For deprecation, there's basically 3 types of APIs: internal, external, and public.

Internal is when its only your team working on the code.  Deprecating these APIs isn't a big deal.  Your team is the only one using it, so they aren't around long, there's pressure to change them, people aren't afraid to change them, and people know how to change them.

External is when its the same code base, but different teams are using it.  This might be some common libraries in a large company, or a popular open source library.  The point is, people can choose the version of code they compile with.  The ease of deprecating an API depends on the size of the organization and how well they communicate.  IMO, its the *deprecator's* job to update old code, rather than mark it deprecated and let warnings fly throughout the code base.  Why the deprecator instead of the deprecatee?  Because the depcarator is in the know; they know what changed and why.

Those two cases are pretty easy.  So long as there is backwards compatibility, you can generally do whatever you'd like, update the clients yourself, or convince the maintainers to do it.

Then there are public api's.  These are basically external API's that the clients don't have much control over, such as a web API.  These are incredibly hard to update or deprecate.  Most won't notice its broken, won't have someone to fix it, won't get notifications that its changing, and will *only* fix it once its broken (after they've yelled at *you* for breaking it, over course).

I've had to do the above a few times, and it is such a chore.  I think the best you can do is purposefully break it *early*, wait a bit, and then restore it.  You send out the usual warnings and deprecations first, of course, but - trust me - nothing will happen until something breaks.

An idea I've yet to try is to let people register simple apps that run small tests.  When you want to do an API update, you run the external tests and contact the affected people.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to be popular is to have clients depend on (web) services.  There are constructs out there that allow you to version your services and allow clients to perform lookups.  This adds a lot more moving parts and complexity into the equation, but can be helpful if you are looking at turning over a lot of versions, and having to support multiple versions in production.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-version/) does a good job of explaining the problem and an approach.